# Putting together a book list on individual vs collective thinking

Tags: philosophy-of-economics, individualism, philosophy-of-political-science

I am very interested on comparing the drives to and results from individualist vs collectivist thinking. I'd like about 5-10 books and for them to portray both sides of the argument. So far I have:

- "The Origins of Totalitarianism", Hannah Arendt
- "The Banality of Evil", Hannah Arendt
- "The Road to Serfdom", Fredreich Hayek
- "The True Believer", Eric Hoffer

Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: J. Henrich (2016) *The Secret of Our Success* (Princeton UP) is book I really enjoyed; *Why Humans Cooperate: A Cultural and Evolutionary Explanation* (Oxford 2007) could be a substitute.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not sure of Arendt and Hoffer's tilt, but I know Hayek is heavy on individualism. Are you suggesting this source will provide a pro collectivist counterbalance?

Comment: An overblown individualism is currently advertised by mainstream neoliberalism as the 'objective position'. Henrich does a very good job in deflating the claim. Instead of an egoistic - individualistic *homo economicus* collectivists propse a *homo reciprocans*, Kropotkin 's *Mutual Aid: A Factor of Evolution*  (1902)  is indeed a clasic (and freely available).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It's on the list!